# react parsing error inside functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parsing, map-function

I'm getting a parsing error on {movies.Map()}. It says parsing error ',' expected. Also it would be helpful if someone would tell me if there was a better way to assign a type to the movie callback parameter. What I have below is what was suggested by my IDE.

```
import {useState} from "react";
import {map} from "react-bootstrap/ElementChildren";
import PosterTag from "./PosterTag";

function MovieTag(genreId = 0, sortBy = "popularity.desc", page = 1) {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const baseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=My_Key" +
        "&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate"
    if(genreId === 0) {
        fetch(baseUrl).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            setMovies(data.results);
        });
    }
    return (
        {movies.map((movie: { id: any; poster_path: any; title: any; }) => {
            return (
                <PosterTag key={movie.id}
                           poster={movie.poster_path}
                           title={movie.title}
                />
            );
        })}
    );
}
export default MovieTag
```

Answer (score 1):

In your component you are returning an array of JSX elements. React components should always return a single JSX element.

You need to wrap your `PosterTag` elements in a `div` or a `React.Fragment` if you don't want any wrapper element.

try this

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {movies.map((movie: { id: any; poster_path: any; title: any; }) => {
        return (
          <PosterTag 
            key={movie.id}
            poster={movie.poster_path}
            title={movie.title}
           />
        );
     })}
   </React.Fragment>
 );
```

Anwering your second question you can make a interface for `Movie`

```
interface Movie {
  id: string;
  poster_path: any;
  title: any
}
```

and then inside callback of `map` you can do this

```
movies.map((movie: Movie) => { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you so much